# Why am I not getting colors with shoulda and test::unit?

Tags: ruby, shoulda, testunit

I have 2 identical ruby setups. One of them is a VM of ubuntu running inside of windows. The other is a native ubuntu install. On the VM, my `Test::Unit` output is colored with green, yellow, and red.

Both of them are running `ruby-1.9.2-p180`, installed through rvm. Both of them have exactly the same gems installed, as verified by `bundle install`. The code is exactly the same, because the source is stored in a dropbox folder. I have verified the `$LOAD_PATH` is exactly the same. Both consoles are capable of displaying color, because both display green when running `bundle install`.

What other possibilities are there?

Comment: Are they running with different terminal settings? Have a look at the `TERM` environment variables.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Strangely, on the one that *does not* work, I have `xterm-256`, which is capable of displaying more colors than the one that does work, which is `xterm`. Weird.

Maybe you should answer the question with an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: So you're expecting software to make sense? You have enough rep to know better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you have different `TERM` environment variables inside the VM than you do outside the VM.

Comment: Thanks, I just added `ENV['TERM'] = 'xterm'` to my test boostrap file and it worked.